# Uploading Photo with ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: file-upload, ios5, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIHTTPRequest to upload a photo with PHP. The PHP side is proven to work(I'm using it for android), and I'm trying to get the iOS component to work.

Here is my upload:

```
NSString *myurl = @"http://mydomain.tld/php/upload.php?casenum=";
    myurl = [myurl stringByAppendingFormat: casenumber];
    NSString *fixedURL = [myurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fixedURL];

    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1.image, 90);
    [request setData:imageData withFileName:@"myphoto.jpg" andContentType:@"image/jpeg" forKey:@"file"];

    [request setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
        NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseString);
    }];
    [request setFailedBlock:^{
        NSError *error = [request error];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }];

    [request startAsynchronous];
```

Ive found this on the internet and when I run it, it fails with the error `2012-01-17 10:52:16.939 MyApp[30373:707] Error: NSInvalidArgumentException`

From many of the documentation and examples I've found online, this should work, but it isn't, as you can see with the exception. Any help at ironing out the kinks? If you need any other information, I'll gladly post it.

Comment: Set the debugger to stop on exceptions, the place it stops should give you an idea which argument is invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There would appear to be a couple of errors in the way that you're producing the NSURL. Firstly, it's only the parameters that need escaping, not the whole URL, so

```
NSString *myurl = @"http://mydomain.tld/php/upload.php?casenum=";
myurl = [myurl stringByAppendingFormat: casenumber];
NSString *fixedURL = [myurl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

should be

```
NSString *myurl = @"http://mydomain.tld/php/upload.php?casenum=";
NSString *escapedCasenumber = [casenumber stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
myurl = [myurl stringByAppendingFormat:escapedCasenumber];
```

Secondly, you're then trying to assign an NSString to an NSURL, so

```
NSURL *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",fixedURL];
```

should be

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL urlWithString:myurl];
```

Finally, the second argument passed to `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` should be a float value between 0.0 and 1.0, so I'm guessing

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1.image, 90);
```

should be

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image1.image, 0.9);
```

If it still doesn't work after these changes, then do as JosephH suggests and use the debugger to identify exactly which line is causing the exception